# Restore and delete the old SQLite database with new SQLite database in android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, database-backups, android-database

I am developing an app where I have to backup and restore my database. I have wrote the code for backup and it's working but I want to restore the backup database in my app and delete the one which is already present there. Please provide the solution for non rooted android devices. 
Thank you!
My backup code:

```
private void exportDB(){
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases/"+DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
    String backupDBPath = "abcrecord.db";
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you can backup your database. So for restoring this database we switch the source and destination files as below:

```
private void RestoreDB(){
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases/"+DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
    String backupDBPath = "abcrecord.db";
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB restored!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        backupDB.delete(); //for deleting the backup database after restoring
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: the database restored but when i try to fetch data, error shows up saying: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_name

Comment: any solution for this problem?

Comment: Well. Be sure to add the name of the table for database. also reinstall the app

Comment: Also try this line for both backup and restore for your database: `String currentDBPath = "//data//your package name//databases//DATABASE_NAME.db"`

Comment: Now the database is not restored. I can see the backup file in my sd card on my emulator. But when I impored it, my app prompted error.